# SwiftUI How to add overlay over VNDocumentCameraViewController?

Tags: swift, swiftui, vision, ios-camera

I'm trying to create a camera scanner with an overlay using SwiftUI.

The camera scanner should have an overlay "highlighting" a part of the screen which the user should focus on when scanning an image.

I'm currently using a document camera view controller which implements Vision (built in library to retrieve text from images), in order to scan text from the image. The camera view is implement as a UIViewControllerRepresentable.

How can I add an "overlay" shape which will highlight a part of the camera screen? And how can I save the image from that part?

The camera I'm using is taken from:
https://github.com/shinjism/SwiftUI-DocCam